# Excluding Specific Terms from WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, taxonomy-terms

I would like to create a foreach loop for taxonomy terms which is for custom post type.

More specifically I want a loop that queries all the products categories, but not the category "special-offers" and not categories subcategories. Bonus would be if, product has no category query them too and order all of them in ASC order (Not like sort products and categories separately. All of them must be sorted at the same time).

So what should I do with my code to make it work as needed?

Current code:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'products',
    'showposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'categories',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'special-offers', 'other-terms' ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
);

$terms = get_terms('categories', $args );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) :

    echo '<h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';

endforeach; 

?>
```

Comment: You are feeding a WP query config array into get_terms, but that is not what this method takes. What valid selection criteria you can use here, is listed under https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Okay, I fiqured it out. But the question is how do I show post, which dont have categories. Unfortunately I'm not that skilled do understand wordpress codex. So it would help me I get a code example.

Comment: Have you tried to research that? https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+query+get+posts+without+taxonomy

Comment: Found the solution. Now I need to sort both terms array and posts array. Then combine arrays somehow and sort them by name.

Comment: This is quite old, but I'm pretty sure it's because you used "categories" instead of "category" as the taxonomy slug. Unless you had a custom one called "categories". Just putting this here for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final solution was to add exclude and term id to the taxonomy arguments. Since it is for taxonomy and it uses foreach loop.

```
$args = array(
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'exclude' => 13,
);
```

And answer for how to output custom post type posts with no taxonomy can be found here: http://www.codeforest.net/wordpress-tip-show-posts-no-category-term

Thanks to CBroe and ste for their time.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. is excluding by that id the only one you want? I'd suggest looking at your original idea again. Hardcoding the ID will break if the ID is ever changed or you need to exclude another you'll have to keep adding to exclude. Try seek something more dynamic.

Answer (score 6):

Your Tax Query is should be looking within another array.

```
'tax_query' => array(
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'categories',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array( 'special-offers', 'other-terms' ),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
   )
),
```

Rest of it seems okay.
Check out the [WP_Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) on this

Comment: Still the same result. Doesnt exclude terms.

Comment: Hmm. Well at least we're on the right track now. Sorry, not currently free to help you debug this issue

Answer (score 1):

Just incase someone runs into this in the year 2022 haha

```js
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```